# Selenium webdriver hangs up sometimes when searching for elements

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm experiencing a big issues about my test script. I'm using python + selenium (2.40) + Firefox (33) to iterate though goods list. There are a lot of structured div elements with id and css styles. 
The issues is when i'm search for a plenty of elements python can hang up for forever. Eventually i'm using a code like this, but the issue still persist

```
self.driver.get("some site")
time.sleep(5*LOAD_RATE)
deals = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
deals = filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute('data-position') != None, deals)
```

python can hang up on the 3rd row from time to time (often) and I can do nothing with this. Selenium should support firefox 33 (according to its release notes).
I also used WebDriverWait, but this hangs too.
Any idea?

The html sample is (from firefox developer console view)

```
<div class='infoTable'>
<div class='infoRow' data-position='1'> ... </div>
<div class='infoRow' data-position='2'> ... </div>
<div class='infoRow' data-position='3'> ... </div>
<div class='infoRow' data-position='4'> ... </div>
<div class='infoRow' data-position='5'> ... </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're loading into `deals` all the existing `div` tags on your page. This of course leads to a lot of time to execute.
Instead of doing  `self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')` filter the `div` tags by `id` or `cssSelectors` so that you'll only retrieve from page only the locators that you need.

UPDATE:
Assuming that you have your data on the `<div class="infoRow" data-position="a_number"> ... </div>` then you can retrieve your elements by `xpath`:

```
.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='infoRow']")
```

You can also incorporate the `data-position` attribute too, in case it's required:

```
.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@data-position and @class='infoRow']")
```

Comment: Good idea, but it hangs up either when search by id or search by tag or smth else.
And this doesnt explain the fact it hangs forever

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your HTML code? This way we narrow it down to what you have and see what can be improved.

Comment: This hangs too sometimes. Sometimes it works really long before hang